# How would I create a reference to a link within a javascript file?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to create a click to link within my javascript file that supports a google map page. I've tried to figure out the the syntax, but I haven't had any luck.

Here's the code:

```
  var point = new GLatLng(35.4068122740699,-78.73926043510437);
  var marker = createMarker(point,"Admissions","<strong>Admissions</strong><br><img src='building3.jpg' height='93' width='140'><br><strong>Go to Building → </strong>")
  map.addOverlay(marker);
```

I want 'Go to Building' to be the click to link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can update this:

```
<a href='#'><strong>Go to Building → </strong></a>
```

in your string.

---

```
var marker = createMarker("all other as is--><a href='#'><strong>Go to Building → </strong></a>")
```

Comment: Thank you! I kept putting " instead of '.